# "Don't be safe, nor sorry"

Tags: neither-nor, either-or

Recently, I saw this statement on a poster: "Don't be safe, nor sorry". I felt that it was not correct and should be: "Don't be safe or sorry".

Am I right?

Here's a photo I took at the shop (in case that rings a bell somewhere):

[image: The photo of the poster in the shop]

Comment: It's somehow playing on the phrase "Better safe than sorry".  As to whether "nor" is the right word, maybe not, but it work's better than "or".  To me it would read better as something like "Be neither safe nor sorry".

Answer (score 4):

The usual phrases *Be safe or sorry* and *Better safe than sorry* present a choice of either *safe* or *sorry*.

This seems to be a play on those phrases meaning that you can avoid both: you can disregard safety and not be sorry.

From The Free Dictionary

> Nor
>   2. (used to continue the force of a negative, as not, no, never, etc., occurring in a preceding clause): *I never saw him again, nor did I regret it.*

Could be applied as *I'm not going to be safe, nor [will I] be sorry [about it]*.

---

<sub>Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. S.v. "NOR." Retrieved January 11 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/NOR</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that the sentence is correct.  Although this usage of "nor" is rare(ish), it can indeed be used without "neither" simply to indicate an additional negative alternative.  The phrase sounds slightly more odd than normal because the verb "be" is elided in the second case; if it were re-introduced, you would have:

> Don't be safe, nor be sorry.

Although I admit that "or" sounds equally OK here, this sounds OK to me; both imperatives are negative.  "Nor" is basically replacing the writing of "don't" a second time.  This is confirmed by [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nor):

> conjunction
>   1. (**used in negative phrases**, especially after neither, **to introduce the second member in a series**, or any subsequent member):
>   "Neither he nor I will be there. **They won't wait for you, nor for me, nor for anybody.**"

A more standard example of this usage of "nor" would perhaps be:

> You mustn't harm him, nor anger him.

Again, "nor" or "or" can be used, although technically "nor" is more correct because both alternatives are negative.  It doesn't have to be used with "neither", although it usually is:

> Be neither safe nor sorry.
>   You must neither harm him nor anger him.

Answer (score -1):

The usual form of the expression is:

> Be safe, not sorry

(For decades, this wording has been used in a wide variety of public safety campaigns.)

However, if we focus purely on the grammaticality of the poster, we can say that the wording should be amended to:

> Don't be safe or sorry

(*Or* is all that is required when presenting a simple choice between two alternatives.)

If you were determined to use *nor,* you would have to change the wording to:

> Be neither safe nor sorry

where *nor* forms part of the *neither... nor* construction typically used to negate two entities.

Comment: This doesn't address the use of *nor* in the adjusted negated phrase, which is what the question is about.

Comment: Yes Andrew. That is the purpose of the question.

Comment: There's no need for *neither* because the phrase already has a preceding negative in *don't* so it fits the "[negative] … nor …" construction already.

Answer (score -2):

It does not seem to be correct to me. What was the context?

The phrase that normally comes to mind is "Be safe, or be sorry".

"Don't be unsafe, nor sorry" seems to me what it should have been. Perhaps someone left out the "un"?

Comment: Just a poster stuck in a book shop.